# Not sure how I can get class labels from Neural Network predictions. Would this be an acceptable alternative to the old method

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science-model

I am currently working with a dataset that has over 300 variables and a target variable with 10 different classes. My goal is to use said variables and produce a prediction for the target variable. Since the target variable has mutually exclusive classes, I've come up with the following script:

```
y_train_1 = pd.get_dummies(y_train["Class_target"])
y_train_1.columns = [f"Class_{i}" for i in y_train_1.columns]

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(250, activation = "relu", input_shape = [X_train.shape[1]]), 
    keras.layers.Dense(250, activation = "relu"), 
    # Softmax is used as the target variable has 10 different mutually exclusive classes
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax")
])

early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    min_delta = 0.001,
    patience = 20, 
    restore_best_weights = True 
) 

model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    optimizer = "adam", 
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)

model.fit(
    X_train_1, 
    y_train_1, 
    validation_data = (
        X_test_1, 
        y_test_1
    ), 
    batch_size = 32, 
    epochs = 3, 
    callbacks = [early_stopping], 
    verbose = 1
)

# The predictions are converted into a dataset and as the sum of each row is 1, I transpose the dataset and reset the index of the dataset to get a column of class labels. I used y_train_1.columns to get column labels for the probability dataset.

predicted_df = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(X_train))
predicted_df.columns = y_train_1.columns

predicted_df_1 = predicted_df.T.reset_index()

new_list = []

# I then use the following loop to get the class labels for each row based on the maximum probability for each column
values = list(predicted_df_1["index"])

for i in predicted_df_1.columns:
    if i != "index":
        column_list = list(predicted_df_1[i])
        max_index = column_list.index(max(column_list))
        new_list.append(values[max_index])

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Predicted Classes":new_list
})
```

The part that I'm particularly uneasy about is the part where I use y_train's column names as the predicted tables column names. I have no idea whether this is the correct way to get class labels or not as the old way of getting class labels (model.predict_classes()) is deprecated.

I'd very much appreciate any form of assistance regarding this matter.

Comment: Instead of looping through all rows to get the max over the different columns, it is much faster and easier to use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to automatically find the index with the highest value. You can then use these indices to get the corresponding labels.

Comment: @Oxbowerce Thanks for dropping by. Would I be correct to presume that the indices correspond to the columns in the one hot encoded y_train table then?

Comment: That is correct, the model is predicting the labels it has been trained, so the output for any new data would also be for the same labels that are in the training dataset. That is also why you can't simply have a new unseen label in your test set, since the model hasn't seen it during training it cannot directly predict it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through all rows to get the max over the different columns, it is much faster and easier to use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to automatically find the index with the highest value. You can then use these indices to get the corresponding labels.

```
import numpy as np
    
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
preds = np.random.rand(10, 5)
preds = preds / preds.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
indices = np.argmax(preds, axis=1)
np.array(labels)[indices]
# array(['c', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

You are correct in using the training labels to get the labels for new data as the model is predicting the labels it has been trained on, so the output for any new data would also be for the same labels that are in the training dataset. That is also why you can't simply have a new unseen label in your test set, since the model hasn't seen it during training it cannot directly predict it.